# How to assign values base class properties inside a derived class object without listing them one by one?

Tags: c#

In the following scenario where I have no control over the Employee class but can derive a class based on that. Is there any way that I can create a list of derived class objects as follows

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    // Other properties may be added here in future
    // I have no access to this base class to modify it 

}


public class EmployeeFormatted: Employee // inherit form base calss Employee
{
    public string FullName {get; set;}
}


public List<EmployeeFormatted> GetFormattedEmployeeList()
{
    //How to assign base class properties of the derived object without assgining them one by one ?

    //I managed to do this  as following

    List<Employee> employees = GetEmployeeFromSomwhere();

    List<EmployeeFormatted> formattedEmployeesList = new List<EmployeeFormatted>();
    foreach ( emp in employees)
    {
        formattedEmployeesList.Add( new EmployeeFormatted
                        { 
                        //assign the base class properties one by one
                        EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID,    
                        EmployeeCode = emp.EmployeeCode,

                        --
                        --

                        //assign the property defined in the inherited class

                        FullName = FomratName(emp.FirstName, emp.LastName)
                        });
    }

    return formattedEmployeesList; 
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you're currently doing.

Comment: @Dennis, Thanks for that. But my problem is the base class may have a number of properties and more properties will be added in future. So when each time base class is modified , I have to modify this function as well:-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use reflection. Make a new parameterized constructor in EmployeeFormatted like this

```
public EmployeeFormatted(Employee em)
        {
            var emProps = em.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var prop in emProps)
            {
                this.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(this,prop.GetValue(em));
            }
            this.FullName = FomratName(em.FirstName, em.LastName);
        }
```